# JS how to know if child class overrides parent method

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a superclass and a child that overrides one of the super methods.

```
class Test {

  doSomething() {
    callsomething({
      callback: this.method
    })
  }

  method() {
    console.log('parent');
  }
}

class A extends Test {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  method() {
    console.log('override');
  }
}

new A().method();
```

There is a way to know inside the `Test` class if `method` was overridden?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `doSomething`, check if `this.method` refers to `Test.prototype.method` - if it doesn't, then `this.method` refers to something else, which means it's been shadowed, quite possibly by a child class method:

```js
class Test {
  doSomething() {
    if (this.method === Test.prototype.method) {
      console.log("Method is native Test's!");
    } else {
      console.log("Method is not Test's, it's been shadowed!");
    }
  }

  method() {
    console.log('parent');
  }
}

class A extends Test {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  method() {
    console.log('override');
  }
}

new A().doSomething(); 
new Test().doSomething();
```

You can also do the same check in `Test`'s constructor:

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    if (this.method === Test.prototype.method) {
      console.log("Method is native Test's!");
    } else {
      console.log("Method is not Test's, it's been shadowed!");
    }
  }
  method() {
    console.log('parent');
  }
}

class A extends Test {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  method() {
    console.log('override');
  }
}

new A()
```